# Get posts between dates

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to extract all posts inside wordpress which has been published between the last 6 months and today.

I'm using `WP_Query` to do this,

```
    $today      = new \DateTime();
    $prev       = new \DateTime();
    $interval   = new \DateInterval('P6M');

    $prev->sub( $interval );

    $args = [
        'post_type'     => 'post',
        'date_query'    => [
            [
                'before'    => $today->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'after'     => $prev->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'inclusive' => true
            ]
        ]
    ];
echo '[POST] Today: ' . $today->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
echo "[POST] Count:" . $wpQuery->post_count . "\n";
echo '[POST] Start date: ' . $prev->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

**Output**

```
Today: 2017-03-09
Count: 7
Start date: 2016-09-09
```

If I do a select in wordpress database, within the same to dates I get 2086 rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(ID)
    -> FROM wp_posts
    -> WHERE DATE(post_date) >= '2016-09-09' AND DATE(post_date) < '2017-03-09' 
    ->    AND post_type = 'post';
```

**SQL output**

```
+-----------+
| count(ID) |
+-----------+
|      2086 |
+-----------+
```

What am I doing wrong with WP_Query? Why did I get two different results?

Thanks.

Comment: SELECT count(ID) FROM wp_posts WHERE post_date BETWEEN ('2016-09-09 00:00:00' AND '2017-09-10 00:00:00') AND post_type = 'post';

Comment: @user1544541 Your query gaves me all posts inside wordpress.

Comment: SELECT count(*) FROM wp_posts WHERE post_date BETWEEN ('2016-09-09 00:00:00' AND '2017-09-10 00:00:00') AND post_type = 'post';

Comment: I am counting all posts from 9th September 2016 to 9th September 2017 (for 1 year).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your sql query you set post date smaller than 2017-03-09 `DATE(post_date) < '2017-03-09'` but in WP_Query with `'inclusive' => true` is Less than or equal to 2017-03-09 `DATE(post_date) <= '2017-03-09'`.
2. You can print sql query generated by WP_Query like this:

   ```
   echo $wpQuery->request;
   ```
3. Try it:

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.post_date >= '2016-09-09 15:19:39' AND wp_posts.post_date <= '2017-03-09 16:19:39' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(ID)
FROM wp_posts
WHERE DATE(post_date) >= '2016-09-09' AND DATE(post_date) < '2017-09-09' 
   AND post_type = 'post';
```

Comment: I got the same result

Comment: dataType for Post_date ?

Comment: I think it's a TIMESTAMP `2017-02-02 09:39:55`

Comment: you think or sure....:)
In ur code **new \DateInterval('P6M');** which means 6 months and in query you doing difference of 12 months i.e. 1 year....so your count going to vary

Comment: It doesn't matter, because I don't have any published post after today @Naincy.

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to expound on the code in your answer. Tell about how it works or what exactly you are doing. This helps newer developers understand exactly what is going on.